# Border on all sides of one sided-skewed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to give a border on all sides to a one sided-skewed box, but I am unable to do so.

The css code written for this is

```
.block{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid teal;
  border-bottom: 2px solid teal;
  border-left: 2px solid teal;
}
.block::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    transform-origin: right bottom ;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    border-right: 2px solid teal; 
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anubhavmaity/pen/pbPJKw/)

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is play around a bit more with the borders and positioning of the pseudo element. Something like this:

```css
.block {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid teal;
    border-right: none;
}

.block::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    border: 2px solid teal; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```